# How create Bottom sheets in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

How create Bottom sheets in Xamarin.Forms?

[image: Bottom sheet gif]

https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html

Comment: Or you can implement it by your self using AbsoluteLayout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46359686/7189343

Answer (score 3):

Use [SlideOverKit](http://www.xam-consulting.com/slideoverkit-xamarin-forms/) for this purpose.

It's available on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlideOverKit/)

Here are some [examples](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit)

The control you are looking for is called [Slide up Menu](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/5d4e2cafbd00a82be79092c9b49c9f6f4e5462f9/687474703a2f2f7777772e78616d2d636f6e73756c74696e672e636f6d2f736c6964656f7665726b69742d78616d6172696e2d666f726d732f696d672f706f7274666f6c696f2f536c69646555704d656e752d694f532e676966)

[image] [image]

Comment: Here is the missing link for the examples: http://web.archive.org/web/20160510021837/http://xam-consulting.com/slideoverkit-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 3):

Xamarin Forms Bottom sheet without a nuget package library.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YourAppName.Views.YourPageName">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="White">
      <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
         <!-- place your page content here -->
      </StackLayout>

      <Frame x:Name="BottomSheet" CornerRadius="20" HasShadow="True" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="10,5" BorderColor="LightGray"
               RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.93,Constant=0}"
               RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
               RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=0}">
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
           <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="OnPanelUpdated" />
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
          <BoxView HeightRequest="5" CornerRadius="2" BackgroundColor="Grey" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" WidthRequest="50" Margin="25,10,0,10"></BoxView>
                   <!-- Place your bottom sheet layout here -->
        </StackLayout>
      </Frame>
    </RelativeLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

YourPageName.xaml.cs Code behind

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
 {
    MoveBottomSheet(true);
 }

 /// The -negative value determines how many vertical units should the panel occuply on the screen.
 private async void MoveBottomSheet(bool close)
 {
    double finalTranslation = close ? (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone ? -134.0 : -144.0) : (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone ? -389.0 : -434.0);
    await BottomSheet.TranslateTo(BottomSheet.X, finalTranslation, 450, Easing.SinIn);
 }

/// This is fired multiple times while the user pans the bottom sheet. This variable captures the first intention of determining whether to open (pan up) or close (pan down)
bool _panelActivated = false;
private void OnPanelUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
   switch (e.StatusType)
   {
      case GestureStatus.Started:
           break;
      case GestureStatus.Running:
           if (_panelActivated)
           {
              return;
           }
           MoveBottomSheet(e.TotalY > 0);               
           _panelActivated = true;
           break;
      case GestureStatus.Completed:
           _panelActivated = false;
           break;
      case GestureStatus.Canceled:
           break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a nuget made by me this is the github project

https://github.com/josco007/CHDBottomSheet

[image]

It also supports scrollviews inside.

You need a relative layout as root view and set your relative layout in this way on the onAppearing method

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    CHDBottomSheetBs.SetRelativeLayout(_rootRlt);
}
```

See the github project for more information.

Comment: MS recommend to avoid RelativeLayout at any cost for performance reasons.

Comment: I was using this solution but it have issues if you use button inside. They will become not enabled too since parent scrollview is disabled.